# Minimise $ab+bc+ac$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$, and $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$

How can I calculate the minimum value of $ab+bc+ac$? (i.e. most negative)

I've tried using the fact that $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(a-c)^2 \ge 0$ but this gives an inequality in the wrong direction.

Comment: Are you familiar with Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: @Travis Yes, but I would like a more elementary way if possible, since such knowledge is not assumed on the sheet on which this question was set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: 
$$
ab+bc+ac = \frac{(a+b+c)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)}2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(a,b,c) = ab+bc+ac = {1 \over 2} ((a+b+c)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2))$.

Hence $\min \{ f(a,b,c) | a^2+b^2+c^2=1 \} = {1 \over 2} \min \{ (a+b+c)^2-1 | a^2+b^2+c^2=1  \}$.

**Note**: See Barry's comment below for a simpler alternative to the following.

One way that doesn't use Lagrange multipliers is to change basis.

Let $u_1 = {1 \over \sqrt{3}} (1,1,1)$ and let $u_2,u_3$ be such that $u_k$ form an orthonormal basis. In this basis the problem becomes
${1 \over 2}\min \{ 3x^2-1 | x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1\} $ and, by inspection, we see that
the minimum is $-{1 \over 2}$.

Comment: how can the minimum be less than $-\frac{1}{2}$? given the first relation you wrote? or I am looking at it wrong?

Comment: @Calculon: Thanks for catching that, I was more focused on the technique than the details...

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to plug $c=-(a+b)$ into $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ and look for values that work?

Comment: @BarryCipra: No, why would $c=-(a+b)$?

Comment: I think what @BarryCipra means is that you have the fact that the minimum is greater than or equal to -0.5. so if you can find one feasible point that gives -0.5, you don't need to look further

Comment: Not sure I follow. Once you have the minimum, you have the minimum?

Comment: @copper.hat, you're trying to minimize the expression $(a+b+c)^2-1$ subject to $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$.  It will clearly be minimized if there is a solution to $a+b+c=0$ with $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$.

Comment: @BarryCipra: Yes, that is a cleaner way of looking at it. I didn't see it... You should write that up as an answer.

Comment: (I guess clearly depends on your sight :-).)